How to access weighted group means and standard errors after using mice and WeightIt?
Some background: I imputed and weighted data from two groups of people, one group in a certain organization and one outside of it. Ultimately, I want to compare how they develop psychological trait X over the next year, depending on whether they are part of the organization or not (so far, I only have the baseline values for X). But for now, I wonder about a different thing.
I balanced the groups in respect to covariates "age", "fitness" and "education". I want to see if groups A and B significantly differ in terms of trait_X right now at the start, given that the rest of the variables is balanced. So I want to see the weighted means and standard errors of each group. I tried this code, the last two lines do not work and I'm not sure why:
# weigh imputed data sets
weighted.datasets <- weightthem(group ~ age+education+fitness,
                                impData,
                                approach = 'within',
                                estimand="ATT",
                                method = 'glm')
bal.tab(weighted.datasets, un = TRUE)
summary(weighted.datasets)
# balance looked very good
# now I try figure out means and se
model1 <- with(weighted.datasets, lm_weightit(trait_X ~ group * (age+education+fitness),family = linear))
avg_comparisons(model1, variables = "group", newdata = subset(group == 1))
> Error: Object 'group' not found
avg_predictions(model1, variables = "group", newdata = subset(group == 1))
> Error: Object 'group' not found

I think the problem might be that avg_comparisons() can't handle multiple datasets? "group" does exist somewhere deep inside the wimids object, at weighted.datasets[["object"]][["data"]][["group"]], but I can't figure out the right syntax to reference it. I might have found a workaround which shows me the mean difference, but not the means and standard errors in every group. Honestly, I think it's not quite a proper solution though:
model2 <- with(weighted.datasets, lm_weightit(trait_X ~ group, family = linear))
results <- pool(models)

> results
Class: mipo    m = 5 
           term m  estimate         ubar            b            t dfcom       df        riv     lambda        fmi
1   (Intercept) 5 3.1886385 0.0003606696 1.534207e-05 0.0003790801  1349 729.9524 0.05104527 0.04856620 0.05116237
2        groupB 5 0.1090137 0.0018477567 6.542353e-05 0.0019262649  1349 840.8954 0.04248841 0.04075672 0.04303009

Could anyone help me fix one of those code snippets so I can see the weighted means and standard error of each group?

Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.

I submitted a bug report, which you can view here. Note this has nothing to do with MatchThem and occurs when using the subset functionality with any imputed data.
